# Register works but log in does not

Tags: php

I have a register/log in page with POST method. this is the form.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
<div class="section">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row full-height justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 text-center align-self-center py-5">
                <div class="section pb-5 pt-5 pt-sm-2 text-center">
                    <h6 class="mb-0 pb-3"><span>Log In </span><span>Sign Up</span></h6>
                    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="reg-log" name="reg-log"/>
                    <label for="reg-log"></label>
                    <div class="card-3d-wrap mx-auto">
                        <div class="card-3d-wrapper">
                            <div class="card-front">
                                <div class="center-wrap">
                                    <div class="section text-center">
                                        <h4 class="mb-4 pb-3">Log In</h4>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-style" placeholder="username" id="Username" autocomplete="off">
                                            <i class="input-icon uil uil-at"></i>
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="form-group mt-2">
                                            <input type="password" name="password4" class="form-style" placeholder="password" id="password4" autocomplete="off">
                                            <i class="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <button name="login" id="login" class="btn mt-4">Log in</button>
                                        <p class="mb-0 mt-4 text-center"><a href="#0" class="link">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-back">
                                <div class="center-wrap">
                                    <div class="section text-center" style="padding-top: 2.5rem;">
                                        <h4 class="mb-2 pb-3">Sign Up</h4>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-style" placeholder="Username" id="username" autocomplete="off">
                                            <i class="input-icon uil uil-user"></i>
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="form-group mt-2" style="padding-top: 2.5rem;">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-style" placeholder="Email" id="email" autocomplete="off">
                                            <i class="input-icon uil uil-at"></i>
                                        </div>  
                                        <div class="form-group mt-2" style="padding-top: 2.5rem;">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-style" placeholder="Password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
                                            <i class="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group mt-2" style="padding-top: 2.5rem;">
                                            <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-style" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="password2" autocomplete="off">
                                            <i class="input-icon uil uil-lock-alt"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <button name="register" id="register" class="btn mt-4">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my process.php i have:

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
 ...do the register
}
```

and it works just fine.
I coded the login and it did not worked. I figured out that $username = $_POST['username'] and $password= $_POST['password'] are just empty. So i tried this just to see if they take any values:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 echo $_POST['username']
}
```

and it is just blank.

Comment: Why not have 2 different forms? You can't have `<input type="text" name="username"` twice in the same form.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix, change the IDs in your login section inputs from this:

```
<input type="text" id="username">
<input type="password" id="password4">
```

To this:

```
<input type="text" id="loginUsername">
<input type="password" id="loginPassword">
```

You can then check them in your process.php file by doing the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
echo 'Username: ' .$_POST['loginUsername']. ' Password: '. $_POST['loginPassword'];
}
```

As another commenter has mentioned, having two separate forms would also solve the problem.